# jquery element duplication in list box

Tags: php, jquery

I have 5 list boxes with the same name. If i choose  the same element in the list box it returns the error message as this value already selected. How to implement this in javascript Or in jquery

```
                <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
            <td><select id="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="test1">test</option>
            <option value="test2">test</option>
            <option value="test3">test</option>
            <option value="test4">test</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><select id="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="test1">test</option>
            <option value="test2">test</option>
            <option value="test3">test</option>
            <option value="test4">test</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><select id="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="test1">test</option>
            <option value="test2">test</option>
            <option value="test3">test</option>
            <option value="test4">test</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><select id="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="test1">test</option>
            <option value="test2">test</option>
            <option value="test3">test</option>
            <option value="test4">test</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><select id="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="test1">test</option>
            <option value="test2">test</option>
            <option value="test3">test</option>
            <option value="test4">test</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

The Query Function i used to check the listbox is selected or not is :

```
$("select[name^='prev["+k+"']").each(function( i ) {
        lsval = this.value;

        if(lsval == '') {
                alert("enter value");
                $("select[name^='prev["+k+"']").eq(i).focus();
                return false;
        }

    });
```

I have the options as (test,test1,test2,test3,test4)
If i choose the same value in more than 1 list box then it returns the alert message as ('This value already selected').

How to implement this. please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the javascript code alerting the `This value already selected` message. We can't help you without seeing that.

Comment: By the way: you can't have objects with the same id.

Comment: Agree with Blauesocke .. you must work with classes instead of id's and can you post javascript aswell ?

Comment: I edited the question. I included the jquery function for check the listbox is empty or not. Is it enough? Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help you but personally i believe alert on every selection is quite annoying 
HTML PART

```
             <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td><select class="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">test 3</option>
        <option value="test4">test 4</option>

        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select class="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">test 3</option>
        <option value="test4">test 4</option>

        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select class="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">test 3</option>
        <option value="test4">test 4</option>

        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select class="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">test 3</option>
        <option value="test4">test 4</option>

        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select class="prev" name="prev[0][]" >
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">test 3</option>
        <option value="test4">test 4</option>

        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

JQUERY PART

```
        $(function(){
        var PrevArray = [];
        $('.prev').live("click",function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();

            if($.inArray(selected,PrevArray) !== -1)
            {
                alert('Already Selected');
            }
            else
            {
                PrevArray.push(selected);
                console.log(PrevArray);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The command console.log(PrevArray); is not working in ie7. Is there any reason? Its working fine in FF, chrome. Please do the needful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Names and IDs shouldn't be used more than once for HTML elements.

I'm not sure how you're storing the data collected by the forms, but you could to change your code to something like:

```
<select id="prev-1" name="prev-1" ></select>
<select id="prev-2" name="prev-2" ></select>
<select id="prev-3" name="prev-3" ></select>
```

Comment: `id` and `name` doesn't have to be the same though, as far as I know.

Comment: @Svish, no indeed. Was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

also you should use select class="" instead of the id tag, because the id tag is only for 1 usage, and the class tag is for multiple uses